# How do I call EnumWindowsProc?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm, trying to list all running processes on my computer.

What is wrong with my `EnumWindowsProc()` calling statement in my short example code. My compiler claims that, in this line:

```
EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, ListBox1);
```

that there needs to be a variable inside the function call. How should I change `@EnumWindowsProc` to a var ?

```
unit Unit_process_logger;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, 
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }    
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

function EnumWindowsProc(wHandle: HWND; lb: TListBox): Boolean;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function EnumWindowsProc(wHandle: HWND; lb: TListBox): Boolean;
var
  Title, ClassName: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
  GetClassName(wHandle, ClassName, 255);
  if IsWindowVisible(wHandle) then
     lb.Items.Add(string(Title) + '-' + string(ClassName));
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;    
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, ListBox1);    
end;

end.
```

Comment: The error message that you should see is: E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeInt' and 'TListBox'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all the declaration is wrong. It needs to be `stdcall`, and it returns `BOOL`.

```
function EnumWindowsProc(wHandle: HWND; lb: TListBox): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Secondly, your implementation doesn't set the return value. Return `True` to continue enumeration, `False` to stop enumeration. In your case you need to return `True`.

Finally, you'll need to cast the list box to be `LPARAM` when you call `EnumWindows`.

```
EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc , LPARAM(ListBox1));
```

Consult the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633498.aspx) for the full details.

Putting it all together you have this:

```
function EnumWindowsProc(wHandle: HWND; lb: TListBox): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Title, ClassName: array[0..255] of char;
begin
  GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
  GetClassName(wHandle, ClassName, 255);
  if IsWindowVisible(wHandle) then
    lb.Items.Add(string(Title) + '-' + string(ClassName));
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, LPARAM(ListBox1));
end;
```

Note also that `EnumWindows` does not enumerate all running processes. What it does is enumerate all top level windows. Note quite the same thing. To enumerate all running processes there is `EnumProcesses`. However, since you are reading out window titles and window class names, you probably do want to use `EnumWindows`.

---

As I've said many times before, I loath the fact that the Delphi header translation for `EnumWindows` uses `Pointer` for the `EnumWindowsProc` parameter. Which means that you can't rely on the compiler to check type safety. I personally always use my own version of `EnumWindows`.

```
type
  TFNWndEnumProc = function(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;

function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc: TFNWndEnumProc; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL;
  stdcall; external  user32;
```

And then when you call the function you don't use the `@` operator and so let the compiler check that your callback function is declared correctly:

```
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, ...);
```

Comment: Just a preference: but I would write GetWindowText(wHandle, @Title[0], Length(Title)); this would make sure that it also works with dynamic arrays and doesn't fail when the length of the array changes. (and +1 for your answer)

Comment: EnumWindowsProc should be defined as "function EnumWindowsProc(wHandle: HWND; var lb: TListBox): BOOL; stdcall;" Otherwise XE10.2 gives exception in the function.

Comment: @Mehmet No, that can't be correct. I can only imagine that you passed `LPARAM(@ListBox1)` by mistake.

Comment: wow yes you were right. But what is the difference between LParam(ListBox1) and LParam(@ListBox1)? ListBox1 is an object, so both cases should pass the address of it, no?

Comment: @Mehmet The former passes the address of the object, the latter passes the address of a variable containing the address of the object.