# Program started with CreateProcess does not receive WM_CLOSE

Tags: delphi, createprocess, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm starting an executable with CreateProcess, if it does not terminate within 3 seconds (testing) I'm sending it a WM_CLOSE
Code is based on the SO URLs in the source.

Issue:

- The SendWMCloseEnumFunc does its thing and sends a WM_CLOSE
- The program does not respond to the WM_CLOSE (within 2 seconds)
- I subsequently kill it with TerminateProcess (the exception with indicator '(2)' is raised)

It is as if I'm sending the WM_CLOSE to the wrong process, but I don't see my error here?

```
function SendWMCloseEnumFunc(hHwnd:HWND; dwData:LPARAM): Boolean;
var vID:NativeInt;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(hHwnd, @vID);
  if vID = dwData then
  begin
    PostMessage(hHwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);    // Tell window to close gracefully
    Result := False;                       // Can stop enumerating
  end
  else
     Result := TRUE;  // Keep enumerating
end;

procedure ExecAndWait(const ACmdLine: String);
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003135/optimal-try-finally-placement-for-createprocess-waitforsingleobject-close
var
   pi: TProcessInformation;
   si: TStartupInfo;
   lResult: DWord;
begin
   FillChar(si, SizeOf(si), 0);
   si.cb := SizeOf(si);
   si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
   si.wShowWindow := SW_NORMAL;           // @@ Of FALSE?
   if not CreateProcess(nil,                                                  // Application blank, then:
                        PChar(ACmdLine),                                      // Full commandline
                        nil,                                                  // ProcessAttributes
                        nil,                                                  // ThreadAttributes
                        False,                                                // InheritHandles
                        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,     // CreationFlags
                        nil,                                                  // Environment
                        nil,                                                  // Directory; current if blank
                        si,                                                   // StartupInfo
                        pi) then                                              // ProcessInformation
    RaiseLastOSError;
   try
      lResult := WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 3000);   // @@Test 3 sec. Wij nemen 10 minuten = 10*60*1000
      if lResult = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      begin
         // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428456/how-to-terminate-a-process-created-by-createprocess
         // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268208/delphi-gracefully-closing-created-process-in-service-using-tprocess-create
         // Try it nicely:
         EnumWindows(@SendWMCloseEnumFunc, pi.dwProcessId);
         if WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 2000) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then    
         begin
            // Force termination:
            if TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess,lResult) then
               raise Exception.Create('Verwerking afgebroken (2)')
            else
               raise Exception.Create('Verwerking afgebroken - process niet gestopt (' + IntToStr(lResult) + ')');
         end
         else
            raise Exception.Create('Verwerking afgebroken (1)');
      end
      else
      begin
         GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess,lResult);
         if lResult <> 0 then
            raise Exception.Create('Het externe proces is gestopt met exit code ' + IntToStr(lResult));
      end;
   finally
      CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
   end;
end;
```

The program that gets called has a WindowProc to monitor WM_CLOSE coming in and that does not seem to trigger:

```
procedure TFrmExternalProgram.CommonWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_CLOSE then
   begin
     Memo1.Lines.Add('WM_CLOSE');
     Sleep(500);
   end;
  SaveProc(Message); // Call the original handler for the other form
end;


procedure TFrmExternalProgram.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveProc := WindowProc;
  WindowProc := CommonWindowProc;
end;

procedure TFrmExternalProgram.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WindowProc := SaveProc;
end;

procedure TFrmExternalProgram.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var i,pc: integer;
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    pc := ParamCount;
    if pc = 0 then
       Memo1.Lines.Add('- No arguments-')
    else
    begin
       Memo1.Lines.Add('Called with ' + IntToStr(pc)+ ' parameters:');
       Memo1.Lines.Add('');
       for i := 1 to pc do
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ParamStr(i));
    end;
end;
```

But if I start this 'External program' from the comamnd line and kill it from task manager I don't see the 'WM_CLOSE' memo line either (also not when I had this debug message in the FormCloseQuery).

What am I overlooking?
This is a 32-bit app under Windows 10.

Comment: First issue: you just assume, but don't check. Make sure you actually **ever** enounter `vID = dwData` and make sure which process you actually found (printing process ID) and make sure which of its windows you actually got (getting window title). Do that without your kill logic first, just to make sure the program does what you **think** it should. Also the callback [must be defined as `stdcall`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13786696/4299358).

Comment: vID = dwData is definitely an insufficient check.

Comment: What about sending `WM_SYSCOMMAND` along with `SC_CLOSE` parameter?

Comment: You might be "barking to the wrong tree" here. First you should figure out why the process you started hasn't finished in more than 3 seconds. For instance if the said process is doing some lengthy operation like long loop it must first finish that lengthy operation before it will be checking any received WM Messages. So it is quite possible that you are successfully sending the WM_CLOSE message to the process but it just didn't manage to process it yet.  NOTE applications proces WM Messages only after entering the Idle state or when forced by call to `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Comment: @Remy Want to make that an answer? This was exactly what was going on, and you give more info than in the current answer by Anton. BTW1 I've looked at EnumThreadWindows but don't see its advantage - both have 5 'hits' on the 'if vID = dwData' BTW2 I know about WndProc, thanks, this was just quick-n-dirty test code.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have moved my comments into an answer now.

Comment: @dwrbudr `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_CLOSE)` is sent to the window when the user clicks on the window's Close button, or its Close system menu item. If `DefWindowProc()` processes that message, it sends `WM_CLOSE` to the window. So, there is no benefit to sending `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_CLOSE)` when you can send `WM_CLOSE` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Delphi VCL app has at least 2 `HWND`s initially by default, the `TApplication` window and the `MainForm` window. You are sending the `WM_CLOSE` message only to the 1st `HWND` you find. You are *assuming* that `HWND` is your `TFrmExternalProgram` window, but it *MIGHT* be the `TApplication` window instead. You are not validating the `HWND`'s class/title before sending `WM_CLOSE` to it. Checking its process ID alone is not enough, unless you send to *every* `HWND` you find.

Also, your callback does not match the signature that `EnumWindows()` expects. It needs to use `Windows.BOOL` (4 bytes) instead of `System.Boolean` (1 byte) for its return value. And it needs to be declared with the `stdcall` calling convention, not Delphi default `register` calling convention.

Try this instead:

```pascal
function SendWMCloseEnumFunc(hHwnd:HWND; dwData:LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  ProcessID: DWORD;
  WndClassName: array[0..23] of Char;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(hHwnd, @ProcessID);
  if ProcessID = dwData then
  begin
    GetClassName(hHwnd, WndClassName, Length(WndClassName));
    if StrComp(WndClassName, 'TFrmExternalProgram') = 0 then
    begin
      PostMessage(hHwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);    // Tell window to close gracefully
      Result := False;                       // Can stop enumerating
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;  // Keep enumerating
end;
```

BTW, you should consider using `EnumThreadWindows()` instead of `EnumWindows()`. `EnumWindows()` enumerates all top-level windows of all processes, whereas `EnumThreadWindows()` enumerates top-level windows of just the specified thread. Since you already know the ID of the main thread that `CreateProcess()` created, you can use `EnumThreadWindows()` to reduce the number of windows you need to look at.

```pascal
function SendWMCloseEnumFunc(hHwnd:HWND; dwData:LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  WndClassName: array[0..23] of Char;
begin
  GetClassName(hHwnd, WndClassName, Length(WndClassName));
  if StrComp(WndClassName, 'TFrmExternalProgram') = 0 then
  begin
    PostMessage(hHwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);    // Tell window to close gracefully
    Result := False;                       // Can stop enumerating
  end else
    Result := True;  // Keep enumerating
end;

procedure ExecAndWait(const ACmdLine: String);
var
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  ...
begin
  ...
  EnumThreadWindows(pi.dwThreadId, @SendWMCloseEnumFunc, 0);
  ...
end;
```

If you don't care about triggering the Form's `OnClose(Query)` events, you could alternatively just post a `WM_QUIT` message to the thread's message queue instead, then you won't have to enumerate its windows at all.

```pascal
procedure ExecAndWait(const ACmdLine: String);
var
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  ...
begin
  ...
  PostThreadMessage(pi.dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
  ...
end;
```

But, if you do post `WM_CLOSE`, then at least consider overriding the Form's virtual `WndProc()` method instead of subclassing its `WindowProc` property.

```pascal
protected
  procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
...
procedure TFrmExternalProgram.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_CLOSE then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('WM_CLOSE');
  inherited; // Call the original handler
end;
```

Or, just use the Form's `OnClose(Query)` events, which already respond to `WM_CLOSE` messages.

```pascal
procedure TFrmExternalProgram.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('OnCloseQuery');
end;

procedure TFrmExternalProgram.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('OnClose');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `TerminateProcess` not sending any messages. It simply, well, terminates the process.

`WM_CLOSE` valid only if you send it to main window of your program, either by clicking close button or manually from another program.